# deduce that there exists a unique polynomial q(x) of degree at most n such that$ q(c_i)=a_i$ for $0 \leq i \leq n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> Let $V=P_n(F)$ (the vector space of polynomials with coeffficients in R of degree at most n), and let $c_0,c_1,...,c_n$ be distinct scalars in F. For any scalars $a_1,...,a_n$, deduce that there exists a unique polynomial q(x) of degree at most n such that$ q(c_i)=a_i$ for $0 \leq i \leq n$. In fact $q(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i p_i(x)$.

The hint says for uniqueness, prove that ${p_0(x),p_1(x),...,p_n(x)}$ is a basis for $V=P_n(F)$. My question is how to prove the existence? And after that we need to use the hint right?

Comment: What are the $p_i(x)$?

Comment: @RobertLewis I believe they are the set of polynomials $p_0,p_2,...,p_n$

Comment: Yes, I understand they are polynomials, but *what* polynomials?  How are they defined?  What does $p_i(x) = ?$

Comment: You need to make up your mind whether you are starting at $0$ or at $1$ (your $c$s start at $0$, your $a$s at $1$, yoru $q$ at $1$). From the definition you are given, I’ll wager that $p_i(x)$ are polynomials with the property that $p_i(c_j) = 1$ if $i=j$ and $p_i(c_j)=0$ if $i\neq j$. Proving they are linearly independent is easy: take a linear combination that is equal to $0$, and evaluate at $c_0,\ldots,c_n$. Then you have a set of $n+1$ linearly independent elements of an $n+1$-dimensional vector space. They **tell** you what $q$ is, so verify that $q$ works.

Comment: @RobertLewis let me think about this.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: yes I am familiar with that construction and suspected that was what the OP had in mind or at least was trying to have in mind,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem gave you the recipe of how to construct the desired polynomial, just put
$$q(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_jp_j(x)$$
and we check that this satisfy $q(c_i) = a_i$. But this is easy, since
$$q(c_i) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_jp_j(c_i) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \delta_{ij} = a_i.$$